# R - faster alternative to hist(XX, plot=FALSE)$count

Tags: r, histogram, binning

I am on the lookout for a faster alternative to R's `hist(x, breaks=XXX, plot=FALSE)$count` function as I don't need any of the other output that is produced (as I want to use it in an `sapply` call, requiring 1 million iterations in which this function would be called), e.g.

```
x = runif(100000000, 2.5, 2.6)
bincounts = hist(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100), plot=FALSE)$count
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe check out the code for `hist.default` and toss out the parts you don't need? For example, are there non-finite numbers? `hist` checks for that.

Comment: Well it's seeminlgy doing a call to .Call(C_BinCount, x, fuzzybreaks, right, include.lowest) - what would be the best way to call that from any regular script? I only have finite values.

Comment: In each iteration, are you creating a new `x` or using the same `x`? If `x` is the same during your `sapply` consider `sort`ing it at the start, as it, generally, will decrease the computational time in either of `hist`/`findInterval`

Comment: Ha no it's all different vectors!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first attempt using `table` and `cut`:

```
table(cut(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100)))
```

It avoids the extra output, but takes about 34 seconds on my computer:

```
system.time(table(cut(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100))))
   user  system elapsed 
 34.148   0.532  34.696
```

compared to 3.5 seconds for `hist`:

```
system.time(hist(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100), plot=FALSE)$count)
   user  system elapsed 
  3.448   0.156   3.605
```

---

Using `tabulate` and `.bincode` runs a little bit faster than `hist`:

```
tabulate(.bincode(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100)), nbins=100)

system.time(tabulate(.bincode(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100))), nbins=100)
   user  system elapsed 
  3.084   0.024   3.107
```

---

Using `tablulate` and `findInterval` provides a significant performance boost relative to `table` and `cut` and has an OK improvement relative to `hist`:

```
tabulate(findInterval(x, vec=seq(0,3,length.out=100)), nbins=100)

system.time(tabulate(findInterval(x, vec=seq(0,3,length.out=100))), nbins=100)
   user  system elapsed 
  2.044   0.012   2.055
```

Comment: Yes but problem with this one is that it's suuuper slow... So that's not an option for me as I have to iteratite it 1 million times...

Comment: Yes. It seems that `hist` is about 10 times faster. I'm trying a number of alternatives right now to see if I can find any speed up.

Comment: Just ran the above solution with Microsoft R Open 3.2.5, the speed is much better. `user 1.34` `system 0.09`  `elapsed 1.43 `. Just may be one option.

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much! tabulate findInterval it will be :-)

Comment: Ha sorry just notice a problem still - seem that in tabulate you still have to add the argument nbins=length(x) to match the output of hist()

Comment: I think it is `nbins=length(seq(0,3, length.out=100))`. I'll make the change so they line up.

Comment: Ha yes sorry that's it! Thx again for the help!

Comment: I get another 10% speed-up from cutting out overhead: `.Internal(tabulate(.Internal(findInterval(breaks, x, FALSE, FALSE)), 100L))`

Comment: Thanks for the update @MichaelChirico. I'll have to look into using the `.Internal` function. It looks like a clean way to pull out some extra speed.

Comment: just a matter of examining the code of `tabulate` and `findInterval` by entering `tabulate` on the console

Answer (score 3):

Seems your best bet is to just cut out all the overhead of `hist.default`.

```
nB1 <- 99
delt <- 3/nB1
fuzz <- 1e-7 * c(-delt, rep.int(delt, nB1))
breaks <- seq(0, 3, by = delt) + fuzz

.Call(graphics:::C_BinCount, x, breaks, TRUE, TRUE)
```

I pared down to this by running `debugonce(hist.default)` to get a feel for exactly how `hist` works (and testing with a smaller vector -- `n = 100` instead of `1000000`).

Comparing:

```
x = runif(100, 2.5, 2.6)
y1 <- .Call(graphics:::C_BinCount, x, breaks + fuzz, TRUE, TRUE)
y2 <- hist(x, breaks=seq(0,3,length.out=100), plot=FALSE)$count
identical(y1, y2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @TomWenseleers regardless it's strange that this is slower... why isn't `hist` just calling `tabulate(findInterval)` if it's better?? I'm wondering if there's significant overhead from using `graphics:::`...